# Дополнительный код

Tags: любой-язык

Задача:

Записать дополнительный код числа `-24711` в *шестнадцатиразрядной* ячейке памяти.

Объясните как решать эту задачу.

Спасибо!

Comment: @frost_doter, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно инвертировать биты числа 24711 и прибавить единицу. Таким образом получиться -24711.